# Modifying an li:hover a class to be different from the rest of the same li:hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the far right "Store" button on FlynnTec.com have rounded lower corners. I've tried all of the selectors that I know but for some reason "#menu li:hover .menu_right" doesn't work, which obviously means I'm not using the right selector.

Please help! I'm new!!

Thanks...

HTML:

```
<li class="menu_right"><a href="store.html" class="align_right">Store</a>  
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#menu .menu_right {  
float:right;  
margin-right:0px;  
}  
#menu li:hover  {
background: #F4F4F4;  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));
border: 1px solid #777777;  
padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px; 
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;  
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;  
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;  
}
#menu li .align_right {  
/* Rounded Corners */  
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;  
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;  
border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;  
}  
#menu li:hover .align_right {  
left:auto;  
right:-1px;  
top:auto;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add style rule

```
#menu li.menu_right:hover  {
    background: #F4F4F4;  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));
    border: 1px solid #777777;  
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
}
```